# How to get the total number of days in a year from the given date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to get the total number of days in a year left from the given date .. Assume if a user gives `04-01-2011(MM-DD-YYYY)` I would like to find the remaining days left. How to do this..

Comment: Including that date or excluding that date?

Comment: dont forget to account for leap years ;)

Comment: Poorly named question as you are not asking for "the total number of days in a year from the given date", which would be 366 or 365 depending if the given date was a leap yer or not, you are asking for the number of days between the given date to the last day of the given year.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's say the date is today:

```
var user = "05-08-2012";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(user, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var lastdate = new DateTime(date.Year, 12, 31);
var diff = lastdate - date;
```

`diff.TotalDays` contains the number of days (thanks @Tung). `lastdate` also contains the last date for the year.

Comment: shouldn't it be `diff.TotalDays`?

Comment: Hi another small help how can i find the last date.. i.e I would like to display Year ending date is  `12-31-2011`

Comment: Try this `var date1 = date.Add(diff);`

Comment: @Vivekh I've added `lastdate` as a separate variable so its obvious where to pull it from.

Comment: To get the last day of the year and not to use literals, I usually write `new DateTime(year, DateTime.MaxValue.Month, DateTime.MaxValue.Day)`.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps just:

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(inputYear) ? 366 : 365
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If you wish you can amend your answer to better suit for the question. You can also delete it if you think it is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

should do the trick

`int daysLeft = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31).DayOfYear - DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;`

Answer (score 1):

`new DateTime(suppliedDate.Year, 12, 31).Subtract(suppliedDate).TotalDays`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try TimeSpan like

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take some start date, add one year minus one day and then subtract the end date from the start date and you'll get the total number of days between the two dates.

```
var beginOfYear = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var endOfYear = beginOfYear.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
var daysOfYear = endOfYear.Subtract(beginOfYear).TotalDays;
```