# How to get the number of days in a year from a given date

Tags: c#

> I need to calculate the day in a year from a given date, considering
>   the year too.
>
> I'm in Brazil, so I'm using in the dd/mm/yyyy format
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine("Please inform the date in format dd/mm/yyyy");
> DateTime dateInformed = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
> .
> .
> .
> Console.WriteLine("The day of the year is:" + );
> ```
>
> **Examples**:
>
> If I receive: 21/10/2016 I show the number of days in 2016
>
> If I receive: 21/10/1993 I show the number of days in 1993
>
> Considering if it's leap year or not.
>
> *Sorry if I didn't explained well.*
>
> *Thanks!*

EDIT:
Some people reported as duplicate question, but I don't think so.

Let me try to explain in another way...

I'm going to receive the complete date from the user in Console.
I didn't figure out how to get the number of days in the year that the user gave to me in the format dd/mm/yyyy.
I think the calc is basically: date that the user entered - first day of the year. But I also need to know if this year is leap year or not.
But i don't know how to do this using DateTime in C#.

Another example...

25/10/**2016** - 01/01/2016 = day **298** of the year

25/10/**2015** - 01/01/2015 = day **297** of the year

I just have an idea receiving the day, month and year in different entrances.

Thank you!

Comment: Almost a great description, but your description doesn't make sense.  Do you want *calculate the day in a year from a given date* **or** do you want  *the number of days in 2016*, because those two questions are very different.

Comment: [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) has lots of useful [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) for this: consider `IsLeapYear()`, `DaysInMonth()`, and `GetDateTimeFormat()`, among others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the total number of days in a year from the given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495802/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-days-in-a-year-from-the-given-date).  The month and day are irrelevant; there are 365 days per year unless it's a leap year, in which case there are 366. You just need to figure out if it's a leap year or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the answers, my question, etc... I figure out how to know the day o the year from the given date...

That's my code in pt-br, but in the format aaaa-mm-dd.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Informe a data no formato aaaa-mm-dd");
        DateTime dataInformada = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Dia do ano: " + dataInformada.DayOfYear);
    }
}
```

Thanks for everyone that tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `DateTime` object set at the last day of the year (31. December) and use the [DayOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
int daysInYear=new DateTime(dateInformed.Year,12,31).DayOfYear;
```

Or check if it's a leap year using the [IsLeapYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int daysInYear=dateInformed.IsLeapYear()?366:365;
```